# Problema com aplicação Laravel Online

Tags: php, laravel

Galera, subi minha aplicação ***Laravel*** Online e deu o seguinte erro:

> FatalErrorException in AuthServiceProvider.php line 9: Class
>   'Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider' not
>   found

Alguém pode me dar uma luz ? Sou novo no framework !!

Comment: Como vc subiu a aplicação?

Comment: Deu esse erro em qual situação? Já tentou rodar `php artisan optimize`?

Comment: Criei um diretório na raiz da hospedagem e subi os arquivos.
Para acessar o link eu digitei www.dominio.com.br/teste/public

Comment: você já verificou se o arquivo `Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` foi copiado para sua hospedagem corretamente?

Comment: Você tem skype ? Sou novo com laravel ...

Comment: Não tenho. Coloque mais detalhes sobre suas dúvidas que fica mais fácil ajudar

Comment: Eu atualizei o composer e agora está dando outro erro, veja http://www.proclimsp.com.br/teste/public/

Comment: @BrunoCesar você tem acesso a linha de comando no online?

Comment: O erro diz que o arquivo `AuthServiceProvider.php` não existe. Verifique se seus arquivos estão ok

Comment: @BrunoCesar to com você no Skype :p

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636772/laravel-5-2-upgrade-class-authserviceprovider-not-found

Comment: Colocou permissão para leitura e escrita na pasta "storage"?

Comment: Problema resolvido com a dica do Wallace, porém agora tá dando o seguinte erro -> http://proclimsp.com.br/project/public/login

Comment: Você precisa configurar o laravel para que o caminho base seja `/project/public/` ou alterar o seu `vhost` e apontar esse domínio para pasta `public`, caso contrário ele sempre vai se embananar com as rotas...